# TabControl redraws through windows on top

Tags: c#, .net, tabcontrol, redraw

I have a .NET c# form with a tabcontrol on the base form.  This tabcontrol is absolutely loaded with sub controls and tabs.  If I launch my application and immediately open another window (in my app), I can wait about 3-5 seconds and the tabcontrol in the back of the newly opened window will redraw itself and the areas that get refreshed are actually painted through the above window.  Almost as if the tab control is redrawing itself through the window above it.

I've looked into every event on the tabcontrol I can find, and nothing is getting called when it is refreshing.  So there's nothing simple to unhook to prevent this.

Any ideas how I might solve this one?

Comment: Oh yes, also.  This ONLY happens when I'm running the Luna theme with windows XP.  If I switch to classic, the form does not repaint itself.

Comment: I've tried blocking all WM_PAINT messages, and this stops the control from painting through the windows above.  This seems really messy and bad code tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my computer is the only one that does it.  I've tried this application on a couple other computers, and they all run it just fine.  Very strange indeed.